# is it safe to convert windows 7 boot partition to logical drive?

Tags: windows-7

I want to quad boot windows 7, centos, opensuse and ubuntu. I researched on internet and find out that maximum number of primary partitions allowed or supported is 4.

The only way to quad boot the above mentioned OS's is by converting windows 7 boot partition from primary to logical.

Although from another post here it looks like its not possible, but i still wanna give it a try.

Please advise is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, windows can be converted without losing your data *always do backup anyway* to a logical partition. It will however need a Primary Partition to write boot files to.

[Win7 On Logical Partition](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/25603-install-win7-logical-partition.html)

On a side note, Linux does not require to be booted from a primary partition,

[Dual Boot Ubuntu on Logical partition](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643891)

Windows Boot loader will only add up to 4 primary boot options (it will not add logical), but if your quad booting, I would recommend installing grub for sure!

If you already have windows installed, this is the preferred method of installing dual/multi boot systems as windows destroys grub, and then you have to re-install grub.

Just make in image of your drive as is now, and you should be able to just install your other 3 Linux OS's along side it fine.